# Get count of all affected rows when executing multiple statements in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

In MySql, how can I get the count of all affected rows when executing multiple queries simultaneously?

I currently do like this:

```
$stmt = '
   update prodb set buyer = buyer+1 where userId = 1;
   update prodb set seller = seller+1 where userId = 2;
';

$update = $dbc->prepare($stmt);

$update->execute();

$queryCount = $update->rowCount();

echo 'This is QueryCount '.$queryCount;
```

But, even though there are 2 rows being affected, I get `$queryCount` as only `1`. Is there a way to get the query count as `2`. i.e the count of first statement, and the count of the second one? I can confirm that there are two rows being affected here.

I'm doing all this using MySql PDO.

Comment: You can't. `rowCount()` only gets the results of the **LAST** query you execute. if you execute two queries, whichever of those finishes last will be the one rowCount() reports on. rowCount() is essentially just calling the `mysql_affected_rows()` api function.

Comment: Someone said something about advancing the cursor... You'd know what that is?

Comment: you're not using cursors. they're only available in stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html says:

> Executing a multiple-statement string can produce multiple result sets or row-count indicators. Processing these results involves a different approach than for the single-statement case: After handling the result from the first statement, it is necessary to check whether more results exist and process them in turn if so. To support multiple-result processing, the C API includes the `mysql_more_results()` and `mysql_next_result()` functions.

The way to do this via PDO is to call the [PDOStatement::nextRowset()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) function.

Here's an example. I run a multi-query in which I insert one row in the first query, and two rows in the second.

```
$sql = "insert into foo () values () ; insert into bar () values (), ()";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

do {
    echo "row count: ".$stmt->rowCount()."\n";
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());
```

Output:

```
row count: 1
row count: 2
```

Comment: Suppose I just needed `2` without the `do {} while` thing? Would that be possible?

Comment: Sure, just call rowCount() then call nextRowset() then call rowCount() again.